# Find lead to hit a moving target considering gravity in 3D

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm trying to find a point in 3D space at which I'd have to aim in order to hit a moving target with a projectile which is affected by gravity.

To give you a better picture: imagine an anti-aircraft gun trying to hit an aircraft flying above.

We can assume that the target and the projectile move at a constant rate, other than gravity in the case of the projectile. We can also assume that the shooter is stationary, since if he's not we can just use relative speeds.

After some research I found [this article](http://playtechs.blogspot.kr/2007/04/aiming-at-moving-target.html).

I was able to implement his first solution, since he was so kind to give a code example. That looks like this:

```
public static Vector3 CalculateLead(Vector3 targetVelocity, Vector3 targetPosition, Vector3 gunPosition, float projectileSpeed)
{
    Vector3 direction = targetPosition - gunPosition;
    float a = targetVelocity.sqrMagnitude - projectileSpeed * projectileSpeed;
    float b = 2 * Vector3.Dot(direction, targetVelocity);
    float c = direction.sqrMagnitude;

    if (a >= 0)
        return targetPosition;
    else
    {
        float rt = Mathf.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c);
        float dt1 = (-b + rt) / (2 * a);
        float dt2 = (-b - rt) / (2 * a);
        float dt = (dt1 > 0 ? dt1 : dt2);
        return targetPosition + targetVelocity * dt;
    }
}
```

With this code I'm able to perfectly hit the target, as long as the projectile isn't affected by gravity. However, I'd like it to be. Unfortunately I'm not even remotely close to understanding the math posted in the article so I wasn't able to translate it into working code. And after spending several hours trying to find a solution which includes gravity I figured I'd just ask you guys for help.

Comment: If the projectile is supposed to hit the target everytime I would suggest a different approach. I use this approach for my Tower defence games. So You know where the target will be at any given time. So instead of trying to figure out the initial velocity vector, how about using a sin function to animate the projectile from point A to point B on a preset path. Basically a linear interpolation combine with a Sin function that offsets the projectile's y-position along that linear path.

Comment: Yea, I thought about that. But I'd really rather not animate it. I just really like the thought of shooting an actual projectile and then just forget about it. Having to animate it introduces some corner cases which I may need to check for and which might result in bugs. Also, having it react to physics only allows you to easily change it's behaviour by manipulating physics variables, like gravity, without the need to change the projectile itself. I can see it working well in a TD, but for my purposes a physics based solution seems more useful.